# How Can I print out the right output?

Tags: java, loops

CS101: Lab #12
Writing Classes II

In this lab you will write three classes: Die, PairOfDice, and Player.

The Die class mimics the rolling of a die. Specifically, this class will implement the following methods:

 A default constructor initializing the number of sides of a die to 6.

 An overloaded constructor that takes an integer number of sides (assume greater than 1).

 roll which generates and returns a random number between 1 and the number of sides
(inclusive).

 An accessor method to read the value of the face on the die.

 A toString method returning the string representation of the face value.

The maximum number of sides should be stored as a private constant in the Die class.
Also use the
Random class for the random number generator.

The PairOfDice class mimics the rolling of two dice. Specifically, this class will implement the
following methods:

 A default constructor that creates and initializes the number of sides of each die to 6.

 An overloaded constructor that creates and takes two integer number of sides, one for each die.

 roll rolls each die and returns the sum.

 An accessor method to read the sum of the dice.

The Player class implements the main method which creates the dice pair and rolls them several
times reporting the results.

```js
public class Player {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        
        Die die1 = new Die ();
        System.out.println ( die1);

        PairOfDice sum = new PairOfDice ( ); 
        System.out.println (sum );
        
}
}
```

```css
import java.util.Random;

public class PairOfDice 
{
        private int maxSides = 6;
        private int sides = 1;
        private int maxSides2 = 6;
        private int sides2 = 1;
        private Random randNum;
        private Random randNum2;
        private int sum;
        public int die1;
        public int die2;
        
        
        public int MaxSides ()
        {
            maxSides = 6;
            maxSides2 = 6;
            return maxSides + maxSides2;

        }
        public PairOfDice (int roll)
        {
            randNum.nextInt (); 
            randNum2.nextInt ();
        }
        public int roll ()
        {   
            sides = randNum.nextInt ( maxSides) + 1; 
            sides2 = randNum2.nextInt ( maxSides2) + 1; 
              
            return  ((randNum.nextInt (maxSides) + 1) + ( randNum2.nextInt (maxSides2) + 1))  ; 

        }
        
        public int getfaceOfDie ( )
        {
            sum = sides + sides2;
            return sum;

        }

        public  String toString ()
        {
            return ( "Sum is:" + sum);
        }
    }
```

```html
import java.util.Random;

public class Die 
{
    private int maxSides = 6;
    public int sides = 1;
    private Random randNum;


    // A default constructor initializing the number of sides of a die to 6.
    public int MaxSides ()
    {
        maxSides = 6;
        return maxSides;

    }

    // An overloaded constructor that takes an integer number of sides (assume greater than 1).
    public Die(int roll)
    {
        randNum.nextInt (6); 

    }


    //roll which generates and returns a random number between 1 and the number of sides

    public int roll ()
    {   
        sides = randNum.nextInt ( maxSides) + 1; 

        return  randNum.nextInt (maxSides) + 1; 

    }
    //An accessor method to read the value of the face on the die.
    public int getfaceOfDie()
    {
        return sides;

    }
    // A toString method returning the string representation of the face value.

    public  String toString ()
    {
        return ( "Die rolled:" + sides);
    }
}
```

I can't print out. This is what I get
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512m
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
problems:
The constructor PairOfDice() is undefined
Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete
LocalVariableDeclaration
roll cannot be resolved or is not a field
The constructor Die() is undefined

```
at Player.main(Player.java:12)
```

enter code here
import java.util.Random;

```
public class Die 
{
private int maxSides = 6;
public int sides = 1;
private Random randNum;


// A default constructor initializing the number of sides of a die to 6.
public int MaxSides ()
{
    maxSides = 6;
    return maxSides;

}

// An overloaded constructor that takes an integer number of sides (assume 
greater than 1).
public Die(int roll)
{
    randNum.nextInt (6); 

}


//roll which generates and returns a random number between 1 and the 
 number of sides

public int roll ()
{   
    sides = randNum.nextInt ( maxSides) + 1; 

    return  randNum.nextInt (maxSides) + 1; 

}
//An accessor method to read the value of the face on the die.
public int getfaceOfDie()
{
    return sides;

}
// A toString method returning the string representation of the face value.

public  String toString ()
{
    return ( "Die rolled:" + sides);
 }
}

import java.util.Random;

public class PairOfDice 
{
    private int maxSides = 6;
    private int sides = 1;
    private int maxSides2 = 6;
    private int sides2 = 1;
    private Random randNum;
    private Random randNum2;
    private int sum;
    public int die1;
    public int die2;
    
    
    public int MaxSides ()
    {
        maxSides = 6;
        maxSides2 = 6;
        return maxSides + maxSides2;

    }
    public PairOfDice (int roll)
    {
        randNum.nextInt (); 
        randNum2.nextInt ();
    }
    public int roll ()
    {   
        sides = randNum.nextInt ( maxSides) + 1; 
        sides2 = randNum2.nextInt ( maxSides2) + 1; 
          
        return  ((randNum.nextInt (maxSides) + 1) + ( randNum2.nextInt 
 (maxSides2) + 1))  ; 

    }
    
    public int getfaceOfDie ( )
    {
        sum = sides + sides2;
        return sum;

    }

    public  String toString ()
    {
        return ( "Sum is:" + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If problem is making that pattern in one line then change `println( " ")` to `print( " ")`. This way line separator will not be added after printed space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `System.out.println(" ")` with `System.out.print(" ")`:

```
public static void foo(int rows) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        if (i > 1)
            System.out.print(' ');

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            System.out.print('X');
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```